# Application to archive a file with multiple passwords

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-management, access-control, 7zip

Is there an application to create an archive (e.g. 7z, zip, rar, etc) that can be accessed with multiple valid passwords?

For example the password protected archive "example.7z" can be extracted using either "Passw0rd", "Passw1rd" or "Passw2rd".

When trying to create the archive with 7zip:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -mx0 -mhe -pPassw1rd -pPassw2rd -pPassw3rd "example.7z" "example.txt"
```

I get the error:

```
Command Line Error: Multiple instances for switch:
```

Comment: Actual product recommendation are off-topic. But the basic idea is to encrypt the file with a random key and then encrypt this key for multiple users with multiple passwords. See [Pattern to allow multiple persons to decrypt a document, without sharing the encryption key?](/questions/71911/), [Encrypt file with many passwords](/questions/138002/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the links and it sounds like it would definately work for my application. It really does seem to get quite technical so I am checking google for some walkthroughs.

Comment: PGP can encrypt a document to multiple keys, though I'm not sure about with multiple passwords. You could also consider a document-sharing site and authorizing specific users through it.